# IPhone: NavigationBar BackNaviItem onClick-event?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, storyboard, uinavigationbar

In the transition between Storyboards generated NavigationBar. 
How do I assign onClick-function for BackNaviItem?

thanks

---

Navigationbar have generated automatically.

I write like this.

```
[[self.navigationItem backBarButtonItem] action:@selector(backNaviItemSenderEvent) forControlEvents:UiControlEvenTouchUpInside];
```

Does not work. (

Comment: do you need to change the default behavior of the back button?, if you don't then don't worry about it, storyboard will do this trick for you

Comment: see my this answer dude.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856363/change-backbutton-with-custom-image-and-textcolor/13856441#13856441

Comment: I need a function.
I need to take action by clicking on this button.

Comment: @Paras Joshi, thanks and how do I get through to the auto-generated "NavigationBar"?

Comment: is this your custom navigation button or default back button...

Comment: what action you want on this back button

Comment: I need a simple onClick-function. I already saw the example below. Thank you.

Comment: yes you can do this task in viewWillDisappear

Answer (score 1):

You can put any code that you need to perform on the back action in the `viewWillDisappear` of your view controller that is being dismissed.

Alternatively you could set the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` with e.g. a Save button and link that to an outlet in your `VC`. The back button is only shown if the `leftBarButtonItem` is `nil`.

Comment: And you can code?

And then I have to do it and forget it. I do not program for the iPhone.

Comment: what is that comment supposed to mean?

Comment: Storyboard generates automatically Navigationbar

I guess I was asking about this: self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this custom Button on `UINavigationBar` , just override this button on BackButton and you can perform any action with click event just try it..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        ///write your code

        UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton.png"];
        UIButton *backbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        //[backbutton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];//this line for set only image on button
        [backbutton setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backbutton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        backbutton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backButtonImage.size.width, backButtonImage.size.height);
        UIBarButtonItem * back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backbutton];
        [backbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButton_Clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back;
}
```

and when you click on this left button bellow method called...

```
-(void)yourButton_Clicked{
      ///Write your code here...
}
```